# Passing array by reference as function argument

Tags: c++

I have the following code for a simple chess engine:

```
int BOARD_SIZE = 8;
...
Piece* board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];

board[0][0] = new Rook(0); ...

void ChessBoard::move(Piece* &board[][], position orig, position dest) { ... }
bool ChessBoard::isKingInCheck(Piece* &board[][], Player p) { ... }
```

However, calling `move(board, position p1, position p2)` does not work - giving for example the following error.

```
ChessBoard.hpp:20:47: error: declaration of ‘board’ as array of references
ChessBoard.hpp:20:48: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token
```

Clearly I can't figure out the correct syntax for this call, but what is it? I have actually reverted to using a 2-dim. array from using a vector of vectors, which I decided makes no sense as the size of the container is constant and not extendible.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `Piece * (&board)[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE]`. I'd go with `std::array` over a plain array if possible, though.

Comment: Thank you I'll look into that. So the array size has to be passed everytime a multidim. array is used as argument?

Comment: All but the first dimension at least.

Answer (score -1):

Arrays are already passed as pointer-to-first-element, so trying to add a reference is almost certainly pointless.  You also need to specify sizes (except for the first, but no reason to leave it out).

```
void ChessBoard::move(Piece * board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE], position orig, position dest)
```

Comment: The reference ensures the array size is what you say it is. For example, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7d74ac0f453057f